# Flink's Internal Workings & Architecture Sources of Knowledge

Tags: apache-flink

What are the best ways to learn how Flink Architecture (both physical and **runtime**) is organized and to understand its internal workings (distribution, parallelism, etc.), except from directly reading the code?

How much reliable the papers on Stratosphere (Nephele, PACT, etc.) have to be considered for the current state of the art?

Thank you!

Comment: There is a lot of documentation on the project website. You might also check out the talk (slides plus video recording) from Flink Forward conference the various Flink meetups. Just do a search on the Internet...

Comment: Thank you. How about the second question?

Comment: This depends. The basic architecture is still the same. But many details changed...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation on their home page explains in detail about the core architecture of Flink. Here's [link](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/internals/general_arch.html) to it. Also as the company data Artisans is actively supporting the flink project, you can have a look at their [training sessions](https://dataartisans.github.io/flink-training/index.html) as well.

Since Apache Flink has originated from the Stratosphere project itself, there are similarities but things have changed at the implementation level.

Comment: Thank you! I found now that 1.0 doc is much deeper than others.